# "These areas of the brain allow for recognition of facial expressions." -- right or wrong?

Tags: grammar

While preparing for CAE, I've stumbled upon this Transformation task. I had to rewrite the second sentence so that it has the same meaning as the first one, keeping the word in caps unchanged and using it.

> 57 These areas of the brain are used in recognising facial expressions. (ALLOW)
>
> These areas of the brain ______ facial expressions.

My answer was "These areas of the brain allow **for** recognition of facial expressions.", but my teacher told me that it's incorrect. [An example of this construction can be found in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allow-for-something):

> Does your insurance allow for home nursing care?

While I believe that my teacher is not incompetent and that my answer was likely actually wrong, my teacher couldn't explain the problem. So, here I am, asking:

**Was using the "allow for" construction incorrect here? If so, why? What should the correct answer be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems fine to me.

> These areas of the brain allow for recognition of facial expressions.

Strictly speaking "allow for" means to *permit* something, rather than *enable* it. Perhaps this is why your teacher felt it was wrong, because these parts of the brain actually *perform* the recognition rather than just *allow* it?

If so, you could express it this way:

> These areas of the brain allow us to recognise facial expressions.

This treats our brain and "us" separately - the brain is *doing* the work to allow *us* to recognise facial expressions.

Having said that, "allow for" is sometimes used idiomatically to mean "enable". After all, your brain only recognises facial expressions when presented with one - it isn't recognising faces all the time. It is a *possibility*, so as a native English speaker I am perfectly happy with your answer, but it is your teacher you have to make happy!

Other ways you could have expressed the same thing, using the word "allow" as instructed:

> These areas of the brain allow for the recognition of facial expressions.